# Как сканировать матрицу с заданным шагом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, numpy

Есть такой скрипт:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(1, 6)
b = numpy.arange(6, 11)
c = numpy.arange(11, 16)
d = numpy.arange(16, 21)
e = numpy.arange(21, 26)


matrixA = numpy.array([a, b, c, d, e]) # Матрица 5x5

def matrix_scanner(matrix):
    print("Входная матрица:\n", matrix)
    rows, columns = matrix.shape
    print("Размер матрицы: {0}x{1}\n".format(rows, columns))

def main():
    # print("matrixA:\n", matrixA)
    matrix_scanner(matrixA)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Исходная матрица (размер матрицы: 5x5):

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
[ 6  7  8  9 10]
[11 12 13 14 15]
[16 17 18 19 20]
[21 22 23 24 25]]
```

Как мне сканировать эту матрицу шагом 2x2, чтобы получались значения:

```
[1 2] [2 3] [3 4] [4 5]
[6 7] [7 8] [8 9] [9 10]
[6 7]
[11 12]
```

И так далее.

Мне нужно подобие этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точнее вот этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исходная матрица:

```
In [63]: matrixA
Out[63]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

---

```
In [65]: from sklearn.feature_extraction import image

In [66]: patches = image.extract_patches_2d(matrixA, (2,2))
```

---

результат:

```
In [67]: patches[0]
Out[67]:
array([[1, 2],
       [6, 7]])

In [68]: patches[1]
Out[68]:
array([[2, 3],
       [7, 8]])

In [69]: patches[2]
Out[69]:
array([[3, 4],
       [8, 9]])

In [70]: patches[3]
Out[70]:
array([[ 4,  5],
       [ 9, 10]])

In [71]: patches[4]
Out[71]:
array([[ 6,  7],
       [11, 12]])

In [72]: patches[5]
Out[72]:
array([[ 7,  8],
       [12, 13]])
```