# Как из матрицы 9 на 9 выделить 9 матриц размером 3 на 3

Tags: python, матрицы

Всем привет, как из матрицы 9 на 9 сделать 9 матриц размером 3 на 3 в python , принцип как в судоку, например из:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
```

В такую ->

```
[[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
 [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
 [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
 [4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6],
 [4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6],
 [4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6],
 [7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9],
 [7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9],
 [7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9]]
```

Comment: поэлементно скопировать не предлагать ? по 3 элемента*

Comment: А если размеры будут больше? лучше через цикл

Comment: А где в примере 9 матриц? как была одна, так одна и осталась. приведите корректный пример.

Comment: вы случайно не [плавающее окно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1128764/211923) пытаетесь реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>https://ideone.com/Zm0vMz</s>
https://ideone.com/PALFZb

```
a = [
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
]

b = [[x for r in a[i:i+3] for x in r[j:j+3]] for j in range(0,9,3) for i in range(0,9,3)]

print(b)
```

Comment: Ответ не соответствует приведенному примеру. При выполнении вашей программы имеем -  [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]] - что отличается от матрицы в примере.

Comment: @passant, исправил. Всего-то переменные местами поменять :)

Comment: Та я не спорю :-). Просто я жду уточнения условия от ТС, ибо оно вообще-то говоря некорректно.

Comment: @passant, ну если `9` и `3` заменить на `len(a)` и `len(a)**.5`, то будет для любого размера.

Comment: Я имею ввиду не размер, а то что "из матрицы надо выделить 9 матриц" А в примере -  как была одна матрица, так и осталась.  И если обобщать на любой размер, то сколько матриц надо выделить из матрицы 10*10?  Или 12*12? Ждем-с ответа.

Comment: @passant, ну там как бы 9 матриц сложены каждая в свой список по строкам - в соответствии с примером. Для 10*10 и 12*12 мне кажется, что работать не должно, а для 16*16 соответственно 16.

Answer (score 1):

9 матриц 3x3:

```
class Matrix(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        list.__init__(self, *args)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return list.__getitem__(self, item)
        except TypeError:
            rows, cols = item
            return [row[cols] for row in self[rows]]

def split(a, n, m):
    for i in range(0, len(a), n):
        for j in range(0, len(a[0]), m):
            yield a[i:i+n,j:j+m]

# matrix = Matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
#                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
#                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
#                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
#                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
#                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
#                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
#                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
#                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
 
matrix = Matrix([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9], 
                 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], 
                 [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9],
                 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
                 [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]])

matrices = list(split(matrix, 3, 3))

import pprint

pprint.pprint(matrices)
```

Comment: Так теперь вроде входная матрица не соответствует примеру. Не?

Comment: @passant ну да, я специально изменил значения, чтобы лучше видеть, как работает

Comment: @passant вот для исходной https://repl.it/repls/CadetblueAcclaimedHexagons

Comment: Запустил (код по ссылке) , получил результат: [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]],
 [[7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]],
 [[7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]],
 [[7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]]  До сих пор мы не знаем, что ожидает в действительности получить ТС, но подозреваю, что не это.

Comment: @passant почему не это? 3х3 подматрицы, как в судоку, что не так?

Comment: Ну, давайте дождемся.